# Sending an html email with an image in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

When I send an e-mail currently from within GAE I receive the email with a Content-Transfer-Encoding of quoted-printable. I am looking to set this to base64. The quoted-printable would be find except the image is not displayed when I receive the email. As it is right now my html which looks like this:

```
String base64StringImg = Base64.encode(my byte array);

StringBuilder htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
htmlBody.append("<html>");
htmlBody.append("<body>");
htmlBody.append("<img src='data:image/png;base64,");
htmlBody.append(base64StringImg);
htmlBody.append("'/>");
htmlBody.append("<br/><br/>");
htmlBody.append("Hello " + name); 
htmlBody.append("</body>");
htmlBody.append("</html>");


MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromUser));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
message.setSubject(subject);
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(htmlBody.toString(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
message.setContent(mp);
Transport.send(message);
```

How can I send an html e-mail with an image in GAE? I have read the following two bug/feature requests which make it clear there are limitations.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=198
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=965

Comment: Did you check the source of received email in your email client? AFAIK, most email clients do not support HTML embedded images.

Comment: Yes I checked the source and everything looks fine except for the =3D that appears everywhere. I didn't realize most email clients wouldn't support HTML embedded images....

Comment: =3D is from quoted-printable encoding and it's ok. It seems that HTML embedded images are not well supported in various email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/

Comment: An extra info, it is not a good practice like `htmlBody.append("<html>");` Use [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) templates, prepare a template and reuse it. In a template, you can use python code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML embedded images seem to be poorly supported in email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1761/embedding-images-in-email/

What is supported are images HTML images attached to email: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1759/embedding-images-revisited/

However, as you noted with the link to the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=965), the second option is poorly supported in GAE. What you could try is create by hand the mail content shown in second link.